# UI Automator viewer is not showing resource id for app created in ionic framework

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, automated-tests, ui-automation

For automating the the android app created by using  ionic( version 1.7.15 ) in the uiautomaterviewer of android tools,

**Problem Statement**
       I'm in need of resource-id to do the automation testing.I'm hereby comparing the my app with pacifica (app developed in ionic) for the proper understanding of my exact problem.

**Expected Result**

The app of pacifica developed in ionic(**version unknown**),installed in SAMSUNG galaxy J2 and automated in uiautomaterviewer,The resourced id is available

**Sample Screenshot**

screenshot [link](https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/ionicframework/uploads/default/original/3X/3/7/371499ba4bf17d4c6d84acfcdb83eb3f2cc937b4.png)

**Actual Result**

The app developed by us in ionic(version 1.7.15), installed in  SAMSUNG galaxy J2 and automated in uiautomaterviewer,The resourced id is not available

**Sample Screenshot**

screenshot [link](https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/ionicframework/uploads/default/original/3X/9/d/9d7d69faf9c0cf98c45c0c7f170ec2db687e2b55.png)

It will be better if i get values for the following fields, 
a) text 
b) content-desc

Kindly revert for any more details and please do give you most valuable tips to sort it out.

Regards,

Madhavan